# Get array with objects from Angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

With that code I can get only array with strings

Html:

```
<div class="form-links" formArrayName="links">
  <input [formControlName]="1"
         class="main-input"
         type="text"
         name="link1"
         placeholder="Your link"
  />
  <input [formControlName]="2"
         class="main-input"
         type="text"
         name="link2"
         placeholder="Your link"
  />
</div>
```

Ts:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  links: new FormArray([
    new FormControl(''),
    new FormControl('')
  ]),
})
```

Result:

```
"links": [
    "input 1 value",
    "input 2 value"
]
```

But how do I get this:

```
"links": [
    {
        "icon": "input 1 value",
        "link": "input 2 value"
    },
    {
        "icon": "input 3 value",
        "link": "input 4 value"
    }
]
```

Also a question - in Angular we must use reactive Forms (FormGroup, FormControl, etc) or it can work normally just as simple js form with html attributes, js validations, etc?

Comment: Remember : "a FormArray can be a FormArrrays of FromGroups or a FormArray of FormControls".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it:
HTML

```
<div class="form-links" formArrayName="links">
<div formGroupName="0">
    <input formControlName="icon" class="main-input" type="text" name="link1" placeholder="Your link" />
    <input formControlName="link" class="main-input" type="text" name="link1" placeholder="Your link" />
</div>
<div formGroupName="1">
    <input formControlName="icon" class="main-input" type="text" name="link2" placeholder="Your link" />
    <input formControlName="link" class="main-input" type="text" name="link2" placeholder="Your link" />
</div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    links: new FormArray([])
});

// Add initial controls
this.addLinkPair();

// Function to add a new pair of inputs
addLinkPair() {
    const linkGroup = new FormGroup({
    icon: new FormControl(''),
    link: new FormControl('')
    });
    this.form.get('links').push(linkGroup);
}

// Function to remove a pair of inputs
removeLinkPair(index: number) {
    this.form.get('links').removeAt(index);
}

// Getting the form data
getFormData() {
    const formData = this.form.value;
    console.log(formData);
}
```

Comment: Have an error with .controls - Object is possibly 'null' Also, it says "Unresolved variable controls "

Comment: Fix prev error, but now - Cannot find control with path: 'link -> 1'

Comment: To fix this issue, make sure that you're referencing the correct form control within your template. You should use the formGroupName directive to target the specific form group within the FormArray and then use the formControlName directive to target the form control within that group.

I`ll update my HTML answer for it

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. Now just need on sumbit remove objects if some values are empty:)

Comment: @Spawnet, as you "hardcode" the inputs (generally we should use a *ngFor), you need "wait" the formArray is created before draw the inputs, buh! it's only you add an *ngIf: `<div *ngIf="form.get('links.1')" formArrayName="links">...</div>`